# How to remove /web/ from Yii2 Advanced Template

Tags: rest, templates, yii2

I'm implementing a RESTful service using Yii2 advanced template [following this guide](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/). However, I'm ended up getting the following structure for the REST service:

`http://localhost/MyProject/api/web/v1/user/1` whereas it should be 
`http://localhost/MyProject/api/v1/user/1`.

How can I remove the `/web/` from the URL path?

Answer (score 1):

If you use apache in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Send all /api requests to api/web folder
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/web/$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to host it on your own server, just create a virtual host pointing to the `api/web` and you will have it sorted.
Here is a sample

`<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName  api.websiteurl.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/api/web
</VirtualHost>`

With that, I can access my api from `api.websiteurl.com`
If you want to api to be accessed from `websiteurl.com`, then just set the document root of your server to point to `api/web`

Comment: What if I'm not using my own server instead something like AWS or Google Cloud Platform? Is there a way to set it this way on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

```
You add below code in web.php file...

'components' => [
      'urlManager' => [
             'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
             'showScriptName' => false,
       ],
 ],


 And Then add one file .htaccess file in web folder..

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: There's no `web.php` file. I have `web` directory inside `frontend` and `backend`

Comment: inside the config directory web.php

Comment: There are three config directories. One in `backend`, another one in `frontend`, and the third one in `common`. None of these have a web.php file in them.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like to use Kartik's [Practical App](http://demos.krajee.com/app-practical) or [Practical-A App](http://demos.krajee.com/app-practical-a). They are based on the yii2-advanced template, but with some changes, like getting rid of the /web directory